# Remove all except 1 dot from text string and convert into number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a text string which reflects thousand separators as a dot but also the decimal.
I want to convert this to a number but retain the decimal.

```
1.056.865.39  should be 1056865.39
6.685.3 should be 6685.3
```

I've tried substitute and replace but I can't work out how to retain the last decimal.
Any ideas how to do this in excel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTBEFORE(A1,".",-1),".",)+TEXTAFTER(A1,".",-1)/100
```

Old Excel versions:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(D13,".",",",LEN(D13)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D13,".",))),",",".")
```

Comment: The text before/after function doesn't exists in my version of excel 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Excel 2013:

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")/10^(1+(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,3))="."))`

Comment: Clever! Does this work for 1 or 2 decimals only?

Comment: @JvdV I hope it works for both!

Comment: I meant, it won't work for 3+ decimals?

Comment: Ah, I see. No, it won't - your solution is more rigorous.